# changing a text with my switch component toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const AudienceManage = (props:Props) => {
 const [change, setChange] = useState(false)
 
 const on = 'ON'
 const off = 'OFF'
 const doSomething = () => {
      if(change === true) {
    doSomething = on
   } else {
    doSomething =  off
   }
  console.log(doSomething())
 }; 

 return (
   <PageContainer>
     <h1>
       AudienceManage 
     </h1>   
     
         <div>{doSomething}</div> 
        <Switch change={doSomething} color='primary' />

   </PageContainer>
 );
};

export default AudienceManage;
```

I have switch component that switches from false to true. I have exported it on to another component where there is a div with an "ON" text that I would like to change to "OFF" when I toggle the switch component. How do I go by doing that?

The first part of the code is the switch component and the second part of the code is the Audience component where the div is and where I want to create a function to change the text overtime the switch component is toggled.

```js
type Props = {
   children: any;
   color?: string;
   
 };
 const Switch = (props:Props) => {
  const [change, setchange] = useState(false)
  

  let SwitchClass = ''
  if(props.color === 'primary') SwitchClass = ' switch-primary'
  if(props.color === 'success') SwitchClass = ' switch-success'
  if(props.color === 'info') SwitchClass = ' switch-info'

  return (
    <div className={'switch-box ' + (change ? SwitchClass : '')} onClick={() => {
      setchange(!change)
    }} >
      <div className={'switch-inner-box' + (change ? ' switch-inner-box-move': '')}> </div>
    </div>
  );
  
};

export default Switch


<!-- Updated Code: still not working -->

import Switch from '../../components/switch/Switch';
import Button from '../../components/button/Button';





type Props = {

}

const AudienceManage = (props:Props) => {

 const doSomething = (value){

  console.log(value);
 }

 return (
  <PageContainer>
   <h1>
    AudienceManage 
   </h1> 

   <div>ON</div>
   <Switch onToggle={doSomething} color='primary'/>
   
   
   
  </PageContainer>
 );
};

export default AudienceManage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your `const [change, setchange] = useState(false)` to the parent `AudienceManage` and pass them down as props to the toggle to use. Then you could conditionally show on/off based off of the change value.

I would also recommend naming it semantically so it makes sense. Common convention is `isEnabled, setIsEnabled` etc. That way it makes more sense.

```
const AudienceManage = (props:Props) => {
    const [change, setChange] = useState(false)
    const doSomething = (value){
        console.log(value);
    }

    return (
        <PageContainer>
            <h1>
                AudienceManage 
            </h1>   

            <div>{change ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</div>
            <Switch onToggle={doSomething} color='primary' change={change} setChange={setChange} />



        </PageContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: I dont understand it. I just want the dive to change from ON to OFF depending on the state of the switch.

Comment: Yes, if you pull change (which manages the switch state) to the parent, and pass it as a prop, it will update in the parent. Then you can use that state to determine if on or off should display.

Comment: I updated the code still not working, and also there is no need for the change={change} and setChange={setChange} as they do nothing.

Comment: Actually, you're passing change and setChange into the Switch component instead of declaring inside the Switch component itself. Can you post a link to updated code or update your code here? This should be working.

Comment: I have it declared in the switch components and the Audience page. can you show me a pen on how you get it to work, because it does not work on my local host. ps. my updated code is above the main post for some reason.

Comment: by passing the change to the div it does change, my goal is have it change whenever the switch is toggled. Don't know if I make sense. but everytime the switch is toggled the div shows either on or off depending on the state of the switch.

Comment: Don't declare it in the Switch component, just destructure the props like `const {change, setChange} = props;

Comment: when I remove it from the switch component the whole code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Switch` component receives `onToggle` as a prop, although that is not something that you have included in your type declaration for `Props`.

Inside your `onClick` handler, you need to call your `props.onToggle` and pass as an argument the value that `doSomething` in your `AudienceManage` component expects.

```js
// inside component function body 

const { onToggle } = props;

// ...

<div onClick={
  () => {
    onToggle( <your value here> );
    setchange(!change);
  } ... />
}
```

I hope this will shed some light.

Comment: I dont want the onclick to be on the div but I want the div to change once the switch is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert AudienceManage functional Component into a **Class component and maintain its state**. Then use conditional rendering technique to show the required text

You are passing onToggle props inside the Switch Component which when call will trigger doSomething function inside your AudienceManage Component which should toggle the state of your AudienceManage Component